# Python access object attribute a la with-slots lisp

Tags: python, common-lisp, with-statement

In [common-lisp](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_w_slts.htm) one can write

```cl
(defclass thing ()
       ((x :initarg :x :accessor thing-x)
        (y :initarg :y :accessor thing-y)))

;; create foo of class thing with values (x=0,y=1)
(setq foo (make-instance 'thing :x 0 :y 1))

;; access attributes x and y in the scope defined by with-slots as
;; local variables and increment them
(with-slots (x y) foo 
    (incf x) (incf y))
;; now foo has values (x=1,y=2)
```

Now in Python3 I have implemented a mathematical model in which I create a dictionary of variables and other components. If then I need to write some mathematical expressions with those variables, after the creation of the model, I have to to write something like

```
model.expr1 = model.var1 + data.coef2 * model.var2 ....
```

but, of course, `var1...varn` have longer more descriptive names.

To improve readability I would like to have something

```
with ModelSlots(model) as (var1, var2, ... varn):
    model.expr1 = var1 + data.coef2 * var2 ...
    ...
```

As far as I understand, each context manager returns one object only, hence the solution above should not be possible.

Do you have any idea on how to implement this in python?

Of course the obvious solution would be to do

```
var1 = model.var1
var2 = model.var2
...
```

but this is lengthy, hard to read, further clutters the context and can also result in obscure bugs as I may inadvertently leave some local `var` variables initialized to the wrong value.

Having several context managers for each variable

```
with Var1(model) as var1:
    with Var2(model) as var2:
      ...
```

is also not a solution as I can have several variables to use in the same scope and I may want to change or add new ones quickly. Having to define a context manager for each of them would then be way too cumbersome.

TIA

**EDIT1**

To comment on Felix solution. The ordering/matching of slots could be solved by the following:

```
from bunch import Bunch

class ModelSlots:

def __init__(self, model, *slots):
    self._model = model
    self._slots = list(map(lambda x: getattr(model,x), slots))

def __enter__(self):
    return self._slots

def __exit__(self, *args):
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    model = Bunch()
    model.foo = 1
    model.bar = 2
    with ModelSlots(model, "bar", "foo") as (bar,foo):
        print((foo, bar))
# prints (1,2)
```

But then you need to repeat the name of the slots twice and with and without quotes...

Comment: I'd just call it `m`, and do the namespaced lookup anyway. `m.expr1 = m.var1 + data.coef2 * m.var2` is not that verbose. What you want is to dump an unspecified amount of new variables into the local context, and it's generally considered a bad idea - that's why you can't find a way to do it nicely.

Comment: I would disagree about dumping variables in a local and context-limited scope being a bad idea. The intent and meaning of the `with-slots` statement in CL is straightforward and improves readability.


On the other hand, the python `with` statement can already dump any number of context-limited variable you want using unpacking . If anything, it does not allow them to be assigned to specified meanings but relies on an ordering that is invisible to the caller/user of the statement. Furthermore, the  scope rules of python already dump variables every time there is a for loop.

Comment: All of those are named - I was explicitly not talking about those cases. I don't have a problem with `with model.var1 as var1, model.var2 as var2` (apart from being verbose and unneeded). I have a problem with things like PHP's autoglobals (or a hypothetical-for-Python `with model:`), where a variable can pop up without being referenced in program. And `with ModelSlots(model) as (var1, var2):` is problematic for maintenance.

Comment: I really do not see the maintenance problem with the hypothetical `with ModelSlots(...)`: if the semantics is the same as for lisp, i.e. you have to name the local variable as the attribute in the model object , why would it create maintenance problem?

Comment: But semantics _isn't_ the same as for lisp, and can't be. Lisp does this with macros, and uses the famous code-data isomorphism, allowing it to treat `x` as both the name of the variable and the name of the slot. Python can't do that: the closest you can come to that is running `exec` on constructed assignment strings, which is slow, possibly dangerous unless you're careful, and if you do it in a function you'd be injecting into wrong scope, anyway. So `ModelSlots(...)` is limited to returning a tuple/list (whose order you have to know to map properly in `with...as...` = maintenance nighmare)

Answer (score 3):

Python supports tuple unpacking, even in with statements. See this in action below:

```
class ModelSlots:

    def __init__(self, model):
        self._model = model

    def __enter__(self):
        return self._model.values()

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    model = {"foo": 1, "bar": 2}
    with ModelSlots(model) as (foo, bar):
        print(foo + bar)
        # prints 3
```

Is this what you were asking for?

I'm not sure whether this is a good idea in general. The names `foo` and `bar` in the with statements have nothing to do with the variable names in the model, so it's easy to mix them up accidentally (e.g. by changing their order). This could lead to very subtle bugs.

In summary, I think it's "kind-of" possible, but may be dangerous depending on your application.

Comment: Thanks Felix. Indeed I think the solution is bug-prone for the reason you state.
Is there any alternative way you would suggest to implement the solution?

Comment: My suggestion would be to just live with the `model.var` syntax. If this is too verbose, you can probably use `m` instead of `model`. But in the end it should not make a big difference in readability. If your formulas are hard to read, divide them into subformulas and assign meaningful names to them.

Answer (score 0):

Leveraging @Felix code to support models given as objects

```
class ModelSlots:

    def __init__(self, model):
        self._model = model

    def __enter__(self):
        try:
            return vars(self._model).values()
        except:
            return self._model.values()

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        pass
```